# Kendoui Gantt removeTask popup

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, gantt-chart

the removeTask method pops up a window asking if im sure i want to delete the task,

this really makes it hard to remove a task by programming,

Did anyone find a way i didnt think of(without changing kendo's code)?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what I was looking for, it was:

```
editable: { confirmation: false }
```

Comment: please mark it as an accepted answer for future solution seekers to easily identify. Thanks